# Unable to override Embedded Tomcat version in Springboot 2.3.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, tomcat9

I'm using Springboot 2.3.0.RELEASE

I wanted to upgrade just the tomcat version from 9.0.35 to 9.0.37 for which I tried the below steps and nothing worked :

Tried upgrading only the spring-boot-starter-tomcat

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

But even after that change, I get to see this in my dependency tree :

```
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.35:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish:jakarta.el:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.35:compile
```

I tried adding this property in POM, but that too didn't work:

```
<tomcat.version>9.0.37</tomcat.version>
```

Comment: Overriding the tomcat.version property (<tomcat.version>9.0.37</tomcat.version>) in your pom.xml should do the trick

Comment: i tried, but no luck!